# C# data grid view last row bug

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am using data grid view in  C# winforms, lets say there are n records that i am displaying after that the (N+1)th empty row is always displayed. how to make it not show\hide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set AllowUserToAddRows property as false.